# How can I deal with null value in excel sheet using Java

Tags: java

Here is my code snippet, I want to print some value in place of null which is in the form of .csv .

```
    private static void showExcelData(List sheetData) {
        // LinkedHashMap<String, String> tableFields = new LinkedHashMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);
                if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() ==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)  {
                    System.out.print("Hello_Check");
                }
                else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                } 
                if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

How can i solve this ,for to be print some value instead of null ,because here in my code i tried so many steps to print some value instead of null in excel file. could any one please help me out ,how can i solve this.Thanx

Comment: Don't use Raw type and casting, specify `List<List<Cell>>` for the parameter

Comment: you can you *CSVParser* by apache for handling all the csv handling issues.

Comment: can any one provide me some link regarding this code

Answer (score 0):

First don't use raw type, specify the Generic type

- `List<List<Cell>> sheetData`
- `List<Cell> list = sheetData.get(i);`

What about an `util method` :

```
private static void print(Object o, String def){
    System.out.println(o==null ? def : o.toString());
}
```

And use

```
if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() ==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)  {
    print("Hello_Check");
}else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
    print(cell.getNumericCellValue(), "No numeric val");
}
```

---

Also, using `foreach` and switch you may clarify you code :

```
for (List<Cell> list : sheetData) {
    for (Cell cell : list) {
        if (cell == null){
            System.out.print("Hello_Check");
        }else{
            switch(cell.getCellType()){
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK : print("Hello_Check",""); break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:print(cell.getNumericCellValue(),"num empty"); break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: print(cell.getRichStringCellValue(),"string empty"); break;
                //...
            }
            if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```